# fastest in ObjC: IsEqualToString:@"" or length > 0?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'd like to know which one is fastest for testing a non-empty NSString for iOS 7.0+.
Note: the strings to test will be 99% of the time from 2 to 100 chars length.

```
if ([foo length] > 0)
```

or

```
if ([foo isEqualToString:@""] == NO && foo != nil)
```

I think it depends if `isEqualToString:` compares the length first (and in that case first way is faster) or if `isEqualToString:` compares first character of strings first (and in that case second way might be faster).

ps: I already know `isEqualToString:` is faster than `isEqual:` which is itself faster than `compare:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply testing the length is multiple times faster (on the system i tested).

Of course, you're relying on the framework implementation.

You might consider a function, which could improve readability, and if the "fast way" changes, you will have only 2 lines to change.

---

In the comments below, I suggested that using a constant/singular/unique string would be the fastest for comparison.

- 72s `isEqualToString:` only
- 22.6s always test `length`
- 15.6s pointer comparison, else test `length` (half elements in test matched constant). this would apply if some of your collection's empty strings were the constant, but some were not. can vary based on distribution of constant in collection.
- 4.6 pointer comparison only

Using pointer comparison is 5x faster than testing the length, and 15.7x times faster than `isEqualToString:`. Of course, you may need to add some overhead when creating your array to ensure all your empty strings are the constant.

Comment: my tests also give the `length` four times faster than `isEqualToString` (on iPhone 3G).

Comment: @Cœur the results i saw happened to vary by length, but yeah, i saw 2.5 to 5 times faster in my tests. i figure 3 to 4 times faster is what you can expect in this comparison/usage. if you wanted to be really clever, you could *attempt* simple pointer comparison against your own empty constant string before testing length. that would be very fast, but there are some things you just cannot *guarantee* at this abstraction level (but it really should work).

Comment: I don't think comparing against the empty constant would help at all, because both `(foo != @"" && [foo length] > 0)` and `(foo != nil && [foo length] > 0)` would just slow down the test with non empty strings.

Comment: @Cœur nope - this can be expressed using a short circuit evaluation: `if (EmptyConstantString == foo || 0 == foo.length)` or if you *guarantee* all empty strings in your array are the constant, then you can omit the `foo.length` test entirely: `if (EmptyStringConstant == foo)`. i will add the results to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Measure it and see.

Seriously. You shouldn't be optimising for stuff like this unless you can see it is actually a performance bottleneck (which is pretty unlikely). If instruments (use the time profiler) is telling you that it's an issue, then the correct approach is to MEASURE your assumptions.

Generate n million random strings, time the code using option A then option B and choose the fastest.

Comment: ok, I tested it 100.000 times and "length" is 4 times faster than "isEqualToString" on iPhone 3G.